# Solr filter on facets

Tags: solr, lucene, solrj, facet

Each of my documents can have one or more entries of a field called Classes, describing some properties of the document, always of the form:

```
<field name="Classes">"<Description> - <TypeLabel> - <OriginLabel>"</field>
```

So for instance a document about food might have the two fields:

```
<field name="Classes">"Yellow orange - Fruit - California"</field>
<field name="Classes">"Small broccoli - Vegetable - Florida"</field>
```

I am using Solr 5.0 and a schema.xml file, where I have a multiValued "text_en" field Classes that I copy to a "string" field Classes_asString so that I can do faceting on the whole field and treat is as a big label.

With facet.field on Classes_asString I am getting the facet counts that I want, but now I would like to additionally filter these results.

For example, how do I only get facet results that end with "California"?

Or, in another example, how do I only get facet results that have "Vegetable" between the two "-"?

I have seen the option facet.prefix, but this is not applicable in my case. I would appreciate any help or suggestions.

Comment: `facet.query` should do what you want - https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#facet.query_:_Arbitrary_Query_Faceting

Comment: I do not see how, maybe I do not understand facet.query for this use case. A Facet.query with Classes_asString:"\"Yellow orange - Fruit - California\"" will not change the retrieved facet_fields nor do I see a way to get filtered facets, since it is a string I am faceting on. Would you have an example query?

Comment: Oh, I see. `facet.query` won't limit the results returned, but it will put the facet results from the query into a separate structure. I don't think you can filter the facet counts in the way you want using only Solr - why not pull the results back and filter programmatically?

Comment: To post-filter out all non-relevant facets in a separate program after getting all facets as you propose is definitely one solution to my problem. In such a case facet.limit=-1 is necessary to add to retrieve all facets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this scenario is a good place to use:

- Index the Classes info as [Child documents](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Other+Parsers#OtherParsers-BlockJoinQueryParsers). You have at least 3 fields in those fields, so it's worth using their own doc for that?
- Then you should be able to facet on the specific child field, either with a current Solr version if it is supported (not sure), or with [work in this ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-5743) that is not merged yet